# Java - creating new file, how do I specify the directory with a method?

Tags: java, file, io, directory

I know how to write a `file` to a specified directory by doing this:

```
 public void writefile(){

    try{
        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\results\\results.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
           //CODE TO FETCH RESULTS AND WRITE FILE
        }

        output.close();
        System.out.println("File has been written");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not create file");
    }
```

But how do I go on specifying the directory, if the directory is set in a method? A method called `getCacheDirectory()` for example. Assuming that all necessary imports etc have been done..

Thanks :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean just

```
    File file = new File(getCacheDirectory() + "\\results.txt");
```

That would be right if `getCacheDirectory()` returned the path as a `String`; if it returned a `File`, then there's a different constructor for that:

```
    File file = new File(getCacheDirectory(), "results.txt");
```

Comment: You'd better not hardcode file separators, and use `File file = new File(new File(getCacheDirectory()), "results.txt");` in the first case.

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to do something the OP would immediately recognize and "get".

Comment: Is it still possible to put file name as relative path in this case? Example: File file = new File(new File(getCacheDirectory()), "..\\..\\files\\results.txt");

Comment: @overshadow Yes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html .